# What's the diffrenence between spark sql percentile function and spark dataframe quantilediscretizer?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert double score into integer. I tried spark quantilediscretizer, but it is too slow. It take hours to finish the discretize process. But when I use function percentile of spark-sql, it's much faster than quantilediscretizer. So what's the difference between these two methods and what optimizations are implemented in spark-sql?

Answer (score 3):

Default [`percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#percentile) provides no optimizations whatsoever. Internally it uses naive `TypedImperativeAggregate`, which collects counts of all values (see it's [`update`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5a7403623d0525c23ab8ae575e9d1383e3e10635/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Percentile.scala#L151-L168) and [`merge`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5a7403623d0525c23ab8ae575e9d1383e3e10635/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Percentile.scala#L170-L177)) and then uses the result to [compute quantiles locally](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5a7403623d0525c23ab8ae575e9d1383e3e10635/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Percentile.scala#L183-L198).

The only real perfromance advantage of this approach is that it is incredibly simple. However it requires O(N) local memory in the worst case scenario (all values in the column of interest are unique), so it is not scalable, and can be applied only in fairly limited scenarios.

In contrast `QuantileDiscretizer` [uses](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/QuantileDiscretizer.scala#L216) Spark's [`approxQuantile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions@approxQuantile(col:String,probabilities:Array[Double],relativeError:Double):Array[Double]), which applies (modified) [Greenwald-Khanna algorithm](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf). This approach is more computationally expensive but, unlike the brute-force apporach, it is scalable and limited by the cardinality of the data. Furthermore its performance can be tuned by adjusting `relativeError`.

Comment: Much appreciated. Your answer made my long time confusion clear! Thanks a lot!